# find duplicate with if statement then delete duplicate

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table (BERTHAGE) that tracks the location of vessels when they are in the port.

When a vessel moves from one location to another location I process the move through a form which is tied into a combo box.

I use one combo box (tied into a query) to give me the current list of vessels in port.

From there I select the vessel that is moving.

Once the vessel is selected I use another combo box to select the new location.

From there I click the Save button and the record is saved in the appropriate table with the vessel now tied into the new location.

The issue I am having is that the prior location record still exists in the same table (BERTHAGE).

So now I have two records for one vessel in the same week, this becomes an issue when it comes to invoicing.

What I’m trying to do is eliminate one of the entries and of course it must be the older entry/former location of the vessel.

Because each entry is assigned an auto-number (primary key) the newest entry, the movement of the vessel from one location to another, will always have the higher auto number.

I have been trying to come up with a way to find the duplicate in the table (BERTHAGE), based on the vessel name and then delete the older entry with the duplicate vessel name.

It seems the only way to go about this is a series of queries (find duplicate, append) and this ends in over writing the entire table each time.  I’m trying to avoid this and stick with the goal of only deleting any duplicates that are occurring that week when a vessel moves from one spot to another.

Though my scripting is average, I can’t help but to think that the best way to achieve this goal will be through something akin to an IF statement tied into the save button.  I was hoping Access would have something similar to Excel's .RemoveDuplicates, but to date I have found not found it.

Looking for any pointers people may have.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToLast
End Sub

Private Sub cmd_Clear_Click()
Me.Boat_New_Loc = ""
Me.CrNum.value = ""
Me.CrDockValue.value = ""
Me.CrFloatValue.value = ""
Me.CrOriValue.value = ""
Me.SelectNewLoc.value = ""
Me.cmd_berthed.value = ""
Me.NewFloatValue.value = ""
Me.NewDockValue.value = ""
Me.NewOrieValue.value = ""
End Sub

Private Sub Boat_New_Loc_Change()
Me.CrNum.value = Me.Boat_New_Loc.Column(4)
Me.CrDockValue.value = Me.Boat_New_Loc.Column(5)
Me.CrFloatValue.value = Me.Boat_New_Loc.Column(6)
Me.CrOriValue.value = Me.Boat_New_Loc.Column(7)
End Sub

Private Sub SelectNewLoc_Change()
Me.NewFloatValue.value = Me.SelectNewLoc.Column(1)
Me.NewDockValue.value = Me.SelectNewLoc.Column(2)
Me.NewOrieValue.value = Me.SelectNewLoc.Column(3)
End Sub

Private Sub Save_Code_But_Click()

    DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE BERTHAGE SET BERTHAGE.LOCATION=False WHERE LOCATION=" & Me!CrNum _
& " AND LOCATION <>" _
& Me!SelectNewLoc & _
" AND BERTHAGE.LOCATION=True;"

DoCmd.Save acForm, "Change_Boat_Location3"

cmd_Clear_Click
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to look at the SQL that is being executed. `Dim strSQL As String:strSQL="UPDATE........:Debug.Print strSQL`. You can then work out what whould be updated, and also why it isn't doing as expected.

Comment: Your SQL statement is wrong. It should read `"UPDATE Berthage SET BERTHAGEActive=False WHERE Location=" & Me!CrNum & " AND Location<>" & Me!SelectNewLoc & " AND BerthageActive=True;"`. Basically, the "<>" need moving.

Comment: I made a change you can see above.  Interesting, it does not add a record, but only updates the current record to location 0 (which we don't have, there are 37 locations in total.  It will prompt to update verify end user wants to update the record, so now it seems a question as to why the script is not reading the input box on the form to get the new location?

Comment: opps, I think I made my change just before your most recent post showed up on my side.

Comment: `DoCmd.Save acForm` just saves the structure of the form, it does **not** save data on the form. You will need to find save the data itself. If the form is based directly on the table, then you can use `If Me.Dirty=True Then Me.Dirty=False`. Otherwise you will need to either use a Recordset based on the table, or else a SQL INSERT statement.

Comment: Currently the form is based on the BERTHAGE table, the initial combo box is based on the three table query, and the final combo box is based on the LOCATION table.  Thanks for initial bit, I thought I was saving the data all this time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212807/discussion-between-dhpa-and-applecore).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than deleting the record, I would advise setting a flag in the table to indicate that it is not active. This means that you can recreate historical data if needed.

In my examples, I am going to assume that the table `Berthage` has a primay key field called `ID` that is an Autonumber, a field VesselID that is a numeric  foreign key from a `Vessel` table that gives information about the vessels, and also has `BerthageActive`, which is a Yes/No field.

If you are able to do the update before saving the new information in the `Berthage` table, then you can use:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Berthage SET BerthageActive=False WHERE VesselID=" & Me!VesselID & " AND BerthageActive=True;"
```

If the new data already exists in the `Berthage` table, then you can use:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Berthage SET BerthageActive=False WHERE VesselID=" & Me!VesselID & " AND ID<>" & Me!ID & " AND BerthageActive=True;"
```

Regards,

Comment: The first combo box I have labeled Boat_New_Loc – this uses the above three tables in a query to populate.
Then I go down to the next combo box which I have labeled Select_New_Loc – this uses a query that is tied directly into the LOCATION table to populate.
I’ve used your second suggestion as the vessel is already in the database and has a location, but I still get the double up?
Private Sub Save_Code_But_Click()   
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Berthage SET BERTHED=False WHERE LOCATION=" & _
    Me!SelectNewLoc & " AND LOCATION<>" & Me!SelectNewLoc & " AND BERTHED=True;"
End Sub

Comment: Please can you update your original question with this additional information and code.

Comment: will do, I'm getting pulled away on another work issue, so I will update first thing tomorrow morning.  thanks and I really appreciate the 'currentdb.execute' I didn't even know this existed.